# d3js scale/axis get ticks via (User) selection

Tags: d3.js, selection, date-range, axis-labels, timeline

I have created a time scale via `d3js v5`:

```
    let domain = ["1989-02-03T23:00:00.000Z","1989-02-03T23:00:00.000Z",
                  "2012-12-11T23:00:00.000Z","2013-04-11T22:00:00.000Z",
                  "1941-04-11T22:00:00.000Z","1940-03-31T23:00:00.000Z",
                  "2040-04-18T22:00:00.000Z"];

    let x = d3.scaleLinear().domain([minDate, maxDate]).range([0, verticalWidth]);

    let xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%Y-%M-%d")).tickValues(domain);

    // TODO fix if ticks/dates to close to each other ( => overlapping)
    horizontalTreeSVG.append('g').attr("id", "xAxis")
        .call(xAxis)
        .selectAll("text")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("dx", "-.8em")
        .attr("dy", ".15em")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-65)");
```

Which gives me this `xAxis`:
[image]

Now i need to select a (sub)timerange from the axis, kinda like:
[image]
and get the ticks/dates which are within this selection.

How can i accomplish this?

Comment: Like brush and zoom? https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/34f08d5e11952a80609169b7917d4172

Comment: you can set the brush to the rectangle of the graph, no need to have a second graph like used in the example pointed by Ryan